# adding custom child items to feature cards

Tags: azure-devops

I have created some custom work item types and added them to the Requirement backlog area of the Backlog levels.  We are using a customized Scrum template.  Now what i would like to do it get them to show up on my feature card and be available as Add Custom Work Item Type.  I would like something similiar to how on an card in the backlog items,  the card with show the number of tasks and how many tasks have been completed, it will also show how many test have been added.  Also if you click the button (3 dots) you have an option to Add Task and an option to Add Test.  See images.

[image: Sample of Backlog Item]

On the feature cards I only have the option to Add Backlog Item,  is there a way to have my custom backlog item show on card and be available in the popup menu.

Comment: What do you mean "custom backlog item"? And How did you create the "custom backlog item"?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify,  i should have said custom work item type and not custom backlog item.  They were created in the Process customization page

Comment: For now, only the default work item type can be added through Feature board. For details, you can find in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For now, **only the default work item type** for the requirement backlog level can be added through Feature board.

Such as the requirement backlog level contains the work item types: `myPBI` and P`roduct Backlog Item` (as below example). And if the myPBI is set as default work item type, then you can only add `myBPI` WIT through Feature board.

[image]

[image]

And I posted the user voice [Enable to add all work item types at the same level through the parent work item type board](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34588219-enable-to-add-all-work-item-types-at-the-same-leve) which suggest this feature (enable to add both `PBI` and `myPBI` through Feature board as above example), you can vote and follow up.